# how to do a join with mongodb in meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

so I have a template in my meteor project like this:

```
<template name="getResult">
    {{#each foundUsers}}
        <input type="text" id="fname" value="{{fname}}"/><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" value="{{lname}}"/><br>
        <input type="text" id="type" value="{{type_id}}"/><br>
        
        {{#each foundTypes}}
            <input type="text" id="type" value="{{type_name}}"/><br>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Now some helpers in js like this using mongodb:

```
    Template.getResult.helpers(
    {
        foundUsers: function()
        {
            var searchUser = Session.get("searchUser");
            var usf = User.find({fname: "john"}, {});
            
            return usf;
        },
        
        foundTypes: function()
        {
            var tyf = Type.find({_id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID("533d63bef0e236f9d76db905")}, {});
            
            return tyf;
        }
    });
```

this gives me a result like:

> john
>
> doe
>
> ObjectID("533d63b6f0e236f9d76db8f5")
>
> barber

This because I have hardcoded the ObjectID of which type_name to be displayed. How can I get this id from john (ObjectID("533d63b6f0e236f9d76db8f5")) to be displayed instead? It's kind of a join query of these two separate I have now. Please help me understand.

Comment: Hey, maybe this ressource helps you. This covers everything about reactive joins in meteor. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/reactive-joins-in-meteor/

Comment: possible duplicate of [returning array of cursors does not show any result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994715/returning-array-of-cursors-does-not-show-any-result)

Comment: You can learn how to do that by watching eventedmind screencast: https://www.eventedmind.com/classes/how-to/meteor-make-a-reactive-join-in-the-ui

Comment: @KubaWyrobek That's pretty well explained but it doesn't cover the topic of custom subscriptions that are required to do the job.